# Can we run our webpack (UI) build just like that in an browser without any server?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a reactjs setup with `webpack dev server`, and a `webpack build`. Can I run the build file which is `bundle.js` in browser directly? When we make a build and deploy it on cloud, what happens and how our application runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you can't run webpack on a browser without any server.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lite Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) to deploy build files locally